# Как проверить равенство двух треугольников в Java?

Tags: java, ооп, геометрия

Возникла такая задача: необходимо, чтобы два треугольника с хотя бы двумя общими вершинами считались равными и записывались в HashSet только в том случае, если в множестве отсутствуют треугольники, у которых есть хотя бы 2 общие вершины с данным.

Класс треугольника (без методов)

```
public class Triangle {

    int v1; // Номер вершины 1
    int v2; // Номер вершины 2
    int v3; // Номер вершины 3
}
```

С переопределением метода equals() проблем не возникло (данный метод просто сравнивает каждую вершину первого треугольника с каждой вершиной второго треугольника и если есть хотя бы 2 совпадения, возвращает true)

Вопрос такой: можно ли в данной задаче корректно переопределить метод hashCode()?

Comment: Вряд ли тут hashcode() можно сделать. Ведь он характеризует уникальность объекта, а так как тут 3 вершины, при том, что берутся по 2 из них, об уникальности нет и речи (3 возможных варианта не могут охарактеризоваться одним хешем)

Answer (score 2):

Это логически невозможно. Дело в том, что равенство обязано быть транзитивным.

Давайте рассмотрим два треугольника (на рисунке красный и зелёный):

[image: цветные картинки]

По условию красный треугольник должен быть равен оранжевому. А оранжевый равен жёлтому. А жёлтый равен зелёному.

Таким образом, любые два треугольника получаются равны.

Comment: В рамках поставленной задачи это верно... 
То есть красный треугольник равен оранжевому, оранжевый - красному (коммутативность) и желтому, желтый - оранжевому (коммутативность) и зеленому, зеленый - желтому (коммутативность). Но красный не равен желтому и зеленому. Оранжевый не равен зеленому и т.д.
Это логически в корне не верно, так как равенство должно быть транзитивным, но в рамках решаемой задачи - верно :)
Так или иначе, hashCode() не переопределить никак, так как слишком мало данных...